# "One-shot" swapping activity monitoring

Tags: memory, swap, virtual-memory, vmstat

I am trying to monitor the swapping activity in a Linux Server in the last, say, 1, 5 or 15 minutes.

One way is to run **vmstat** and keep watching **si** and **so** counters during these intervals.

However how can I check as a "one-shot" action (e.g. through a Nagios plugin) for a value showing the swapping activity during the aforementioned intervals?

In other words I need a way to *instantly* check whether my Server is actively swapping.

Answer (score 1):

Believe you could use `/proc/vmstat` output, say with

```
cat /proc/vmstat | grep pswp
```

command.

This will show you swap in and swap out counters.

Or:

only `si`:

```
vmstat 1 1 | awk 'NR == 1 {next} NR == 2 {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) fields[$i] = i; next} {split($0, data); item = data[fields["si"]]; print item; totals[fields["si"]] += item} NR >= 6 + 2 {exit}'
```

only `so`:

```
vmstat 1 1 | awk 'NR == 1 {next} NR == 2 {for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) fields[$i] = i; next} {split($0, data); item = data[fields["si"]]; print item; totals[fields["so"]] += item} NR >= 6 + 2 {exit}'
```

Comment: alternatively, if you intend to use it in Nagios, try https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/System-Metrics/Memory/Check-swap-activity-on-Linux/details